# How to give access to Content Management of experience cloud site?

Tags: permission-sets, experience-cloud, salesforce-cms

I cannot give access to the Content Management workspace to other users via permission-set. My users can only see 'Content Targeting' instead of 'Content Management', so they can't access the 'Content' tab to be able to assign topics to the articles they have written in Salesforce CMS

These are the settings I've tried:

- Permission set is member of Community User is added as Contributor to
  Community with the Experience Admin role
- User profile has CMS
  Channels/Experiences/Home/Workspace tab settings = Default On
- User is
  added  as Contributor to Workspace with the Content Admin role
- Assign
  topics is enabled in the permission set Manage Experiences is enabled
  in the permission set

What my users see:

[image: Content targeting]

What I want they to see:

[image: Content management]

My org is a sandbox.

Thanks very much, any help is appreciated.

Comment: Does this help - https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000320229&type=1&mode=1 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We faced this same problem today, and we found out why: in order to be able to associate articles and visualize the content manager, the user needs to have the knowledge user tag in his registration.

Comment: Thank you very much, that worked! I think this needs to be added to the documentation on the permissions-needed section because I didn't see it and it really gave me a headache. Thanks for sharing.